# WAMP Server redirects to localhost from ip address

Tags: php, windows, wamp, wampserver

[image: Before Click Moodle Folder in WAMP Server 3.0.5]

In this picture you can see my URL is 192.168.1.150, If i click on the moodle folder listed in the Index URL becomes localhost.

I am using WAMP 3.0.6 on windows 10. what i want URL as IP not want to direct to localhost. because when i am click from another network computer that is also same problem.

[image: After click on moodle folder]

Comment: do you have a index file in moodle folder?

Comment: yes i have the index file its works properly

Comment: Dont you need to use `192.168.1.150/moodle-latest-32/moodle/` from the other PC. Or move the contents of `moodle` folder back into the `moodle-latest-32` folder

Comment: Please post your httpd-vhosts.conf and/or .htaccess files (or the relevant sections from httpd.conf if you define your host directly there). Most likely there is a rewrite rule or something similar at play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of **$CFG->wwwroot** in your config.php file. If you dont want to redirect
set your ip to this variable .Example:

```
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://192.168.1.75/moodle';
```

Comment: I don't think PHP has anything to do with the OP's question. It looks like a basic Apache HTTPD setting.

Answer (score 0):

Changing sites url from localhost to ip, worked for me...
www - vtiger - config.inc.php
---- site url to http://192.168.0.105/myproject

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).